# Reset Select Item - React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a form which includes a select dropdown (items are populated via an api call). When I leave the screen I would like to be able to reset this back to it's initial state (Default state is a placeholder - Select Event)

I can clear text and textarea inputs within a `useFocusEffect()` but struggling with understanding how to reset a select dropdown

To reset the select dropdown i have tried `setEventTypeData([]);` but when navigating back to the screen, the last selected option is still selected (text inputs have been cleared though)

```
export const CreateNewEvent = ({navigation}) => {
  const globalContext = useContext(AppContext);
  const userId = globalContext.userInfo.id;
  // dropdown populated with this
  const [eventTypeData, setEventTypeData] = useState([]);
  const [newEventDescription, setEventDescription] = useState('');
  const [newEventLimit, setEventLimit] = useState(0);

  const clearFormData = () => {
    setEventTypeData([]); // tried setting back to original state but does not work
    setEventDescription('');
    setEventLimit(0);
  };

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const body = JSON.stringify({userId});
      fetch(eventTypesUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json',
        },
        body: body,
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setEventTypeData(json))
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));

    return () => {
      // Run logic when the user leaves screen,
      // Clear form
      clearFormData();
    };
  }, [userId]),
);

// Select Dropdown
{/* Event Name Select Field */}
<FormControl isRequired isInvalid={'eventName' in errors}>
  <FormControl.Label>Select Event</FormControl.Label>
  <Select
    onValueChange={newEventName =>
    updateEventNameAndDescription(newEventName)
  }
    placeholder="Select Event"
    {eventTypeData.map(event => (
      <Select.Item
        key={event.id}
        label={event.name}
        value={event.name}
       />
     ))}
  </Select>
}
```

How can i ensure that when navigating back to this screen that the Select dropdown is reset to its original state

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a bit more code

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite your example. I hope this help. You forget to unsubscribe
from API call

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFocused) {
      clearFormData()
    }
  }, [isFocused]);

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const body = JSON.stringify({ userId });
      const unsubscribe = fetch(eventTypesUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
        body: body,
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => setEventTypeData(json))
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false));

      return () => unsubscribe();
      };
    }, [userId]),
  );
```

Comment: I tried this initially but it does not change the dropdown menu, the last selected item still remains when navigating back to the screen

Comment: I corrected the answer. Please try . Pay attention to array of dependecies in useCallback

Comment: Still the same behaviour I'm afraid, I cant remove the userId dependency, it's needed

Answer (score 0):

```
    export const CreateNewEvent = ({navigation}) => {
    const globalContext = useContext(AppContext);
    const userId = globalContext.userInfo.id;
    // dropdown populated with this
    const [eventTypeData, setEventTypeData] = useState([]);
    const [newEventDescription, setEventDescription] = useState('');
    const [newEventLimit, setEventLimit] = useState(0);

    const [selectedEventName, setSelectedEventName] = useState(); 
  
    const clearFormData = () => {
        setSelectedEventName(); 
        setEventDescription('');
        setEventLimit(0);
      };

    useEffect(() => {
        selectedEventName ? updateEventNameAndDescription(selectedEventName) : clearFormData();

    }, [selectedEventName])
  
    useFocusEffect(
      React.useCallback(() => {
        const body = JSON.stringify({userId});
        fetch(eventTypesUrl, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Accept: 'application/json',
          },
          body: body,
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => setEventTypeData(json))
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false));

      return () => {
        // Run logic when the user leaves screen,
        // Clear form
        clearFormData();
      };
    }, [userId]),
  );
  
  // Select Dropdown
  {/* Event Name Select Field */}
  <FormControl isRequired isInvalid={'eventName' in errors}>
    <FormControl.Label>Select Event</FormControl.Label>
    <Select
      value={selectedEventName}
      onValueChange={newEventName =>
        setSelectedEventName(newEventName)
    }
      placeholder="Select Event"
      {eventTypeData.map(event => (
        <Select.Item
          key={event.id}
          label={event.name}
          value={event.name}
         />
       ))}
    </Select>
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using React Native Picker or something related, That picker is bound to the device native Select component, This has more performance benefit as it's not run on JavaScript thread, React rerendering will not affect that component.

But in this situation, we need to force this component to unmount when the user leaves the screen or mount when the screen is focused.

```js
// Top-level import
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';


// Inside functional component

 const isFocused = useIsFocused();


// Force <Select> to unmount or mount when screen focused


{ isFocused &&  <Select
      value={selectedEventName}
      onValueChange={newEventName =>
        setSelectedEventName(newEventName)
    }
      placeholder="Select Event"
      {eventTypeData.map(event => (
        <Select.Item
          key={event.id}
          label={event.name}
          value={event.name}
         />
       ))}
    </Select>}
```